# What would be a good powerbuilding routine for mass and strength?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, powerlifting

If I focus only in strength training I tend not to gain much size and if I stop doing core lifts for even I week, I tend to lose the 1RM numbers quite easily. Therefore I am looking to develop a routine to hit muscle twice a week focusing on increasing the strength on core lifts while doing accessories for hypertrophy.

**Edit:**

Okey lemme explain, I have had my first powerlifting meet last year, I was in the 64kg category.

Now some weeks prior to this, I started to train 1RM and eating plenty. I gained a few kgs and also my strength gain was decent, but I didn't look as though I had gained much extra muscle, it was just overall increase in bodyweight. That's why I like high volume training for increased hypertrophy, the increase in muscle mass gain is more prominent, specially in small groups like delts or biceps, therefore am looking for the benefits of both types of training.

Comment: How do you know that you gain so much less size by following a strength routine? Building muscle takes years, I find it interesting that you are able to make such an observation

Comment: I am more concerned with strength loss if I stick to pure bodybuilding style routine,but if I follow only strength types like madcow or candito then my hypertrophy is not so much as my weight doesn't vary much neither do I feel the volume is as High.

Comment: Body weight gain has something to do with how much you eat, doesn't it? If you don't gain much weight following a certain routine, you are not eating enough. If you are gaining mostly fat, you are either eating too much or do something wrong in the gym, but what you are saying doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: Okey lemme explain,I have had my first powerlifting meet last year,I was in 64kg category,now some weeks prior to this,I started to train 1RM and eating plenty.I gained a few kgs and  also my strength gain was decent,but I didn't look as i have gained extra muscles much,it was just overall increase in bw,that's why I like high volume training for increased hypertrophy,the increase in muscle mass gain is more prominent, specially in small groups like delts or biceps, therefore am looking for the benefits of both types of training.

Comment: I see, best include this via edit in your original post.

Comment: "... a routine to hit muscle twice a week focusing on increasing the strength on core lifts while doing accessories for hypertrophy." - isn't that the answer? Go heavy on the big compound lifts, and perform higher rep sets to acheive hypertrophy for accessory/isolation lifts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you answered this yourself: "[...] a routine to hit muscle twice a week focusing on increasing the strength on core lifts while doing accessories for hypertrophy." You can also use the power of Google to find some ideas for [powerbuilding routines](https://barbend.com/powerbuilding-workout-routine/).

The program I'm currently following might be interesting to you. It is a 4 day *Texas Method* split that hits the major lifts twice a week. Currently, I run it with minimal accessory workouts simply due to time constraints but they could be easily added (I noted them in brackets).

```
MO: 1x5 RM SQUAT, 5x5 DEADLIFT @ 85% 5RM (+ lower acc. - 3-4 workouts w/ 3 x 8-15)
TU: 1x5 RM BENCH, 5x5 OVERHEAD @ 85% 5RM (+ upper acc. - 3-4 workouts w/ 3 x 8-15)
WE: -
TH: 1x5 RM DEADLIFT, 5x5 SQUAT @ 85% 5RM (+ lower acc. - 3-4 workouts w/ 3 x 8-15)
FR: 1x5 RM OVERHEAD, 5x5 BENCH @ 85% 5RM (+ upper acc. - 3-4 workouts w/ 3 x 8-15)
SA: -
SU: -
```

This program works as a linear progression. [Use your current 1RM to calculate a theoretical 5RM](https://strengthlevel.com/one-rep-max-calculator) then each week that you successfully lift your 5RM increase the weight by 5 lb for squat/deads, 2.5 lb for bench/overhead. Once you get rolling, the idea is that you're setting a new 5 rep max every week. When you miss the 5RM, don't increase the weight. If you miss a few times you can deload but you should gauge your external factors (eating, sleeping, stress).

I like this program, so far. I do 4 or 5 warm-up sets to build-up to the 1x5 or the 5x5. I find that the volume leaves me feeling like I got a more complete workout. Testing your 5RM is personally less taxing than trying for a new 1RM. I've added in extra workouts on Wednesday, Saturday, and Sunday as well if I feel I missed something in the week or I ran out of time on the main days.